# C programming_--Program dumped- I wrote this code to check if the number duplicates in array and should start at 1 while the code starts at 11 too

Tags: arrays, c

The code should check if the number duplicates or not while the code gets dumped. Can you please help me figure it out

A) Write a function that takes in an array of ints as input. This function checks to see if there are any duplicate values in the array. If there are, return true (or 1). If there are not, return false (or 0).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
bool part_A (int array_A[10]);

int main ()
//THIS IS THE MAIN FUNCTION
{
int array_A [10];
int i=0;

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++);
{
    printf("Input number %d: ", i+1);
    scanf("%d", &array_A[i]);
}
int return_A = part_A (array_A);
//function

if (return_A == true)
{
      printf("There are duplicate values.\n");
}
else
{
    printf ("All values are unique.\n");
}

printf("-----------------\n");

return 0;
}


bool part_A (int array_A[10])
//function 
{
int i, j;
//making loop and checking
for (i=0; i<10; i++);
    for (j=i+1; j<10; j++);
    {
    if (array_A[i]== array_A[j]);
    //checking for duplicates
        return true;
    //if repeated return true
    }
   
    return false;
 //if no duplicates returning false which means unique value
 
}
```

Comment: `for (i=0; i<10; i++);` - the `;` is bad. Take the habit of declaring the loop variables inside the for itself (`for (int i = ...`), that would have enabled the compiler to tell you something was wrong.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show? What happens when you build it (with extra warnings enabled)? What happens when you run it? What do you expect to happen when you run it? What is the input you give the program? What is the output you get? What is the output you expect? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: You should post your errors logs along with your code when asking a question. This is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>

//function 
bool part_A (int array_A[10]) {
//making loop and checking
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)  {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 10; j++) {
            //checking for duplicates
            //if repeated return true
            if (array_A[i] == array_A[j])
                return true;
        }
   
    }
    //if no duplicates returning false which means unique value
    return false;
}

int main ()
//THIS IS THE MAIN FUNCTION
{
int array_A[10];

printf("Input 10 elements in the array :\n");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("Input number %d: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &array_A[i]);
}

printf("\nElements in array are: ");  
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)  {  
    printf("%d  ", array_A[i]);  
} 
printf("\n");

int return_A = part_A (array_A);
//function

if (return_A == true) {
      printf("There are duplicate values.\n");
} else {
    printf ("All values are unique.\n");
}

printf("-----------------\n");

return 0;
}
```

Executuion:

```
$ gcc dup.c 
$ ./a.out 
Input 10 elements in the array :
Input number 0: 10
Input number 1: 9
Input number 2: 9
Input number 3: 8
Input number 4: 7
Input number 5: 6
Input number 6: 5
Input number 7: 4
Input number 8: 3
Input number 9: 2

Elements in array are: 10  9  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  
There are duplicate values.
-----------------
$ ./a.out 
Input 10 elements in the array :
Input number 0: 10
Input number 1: 9
Input number 2: 8
Input number 3: 7
Input number 4: 6
Input number 5: 5
Input number 6: 4
Input number 7: 3
Input number 8: 2
Input number 9: 1

Elements in array are: 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  
All values are unique.
-----------------
```